# Executable gives different version information on two machines

Tags: windows, powershell, delphi

I have built a Win32-executable with a VERSIONINFO resource (details see below) that gives different version-information when checked from two different machines.

The exe-file is kept on a shared drive, so I am reasonably confident it is indeed the same file.

Machine A is my development computer running Windows 7 Enterprise in 64bit. It is where the executable was built. On machine A I get what I am expecting, in Windows Explorer it gives me this:

[image: Screenshot from Windows Explorer on Machine A]

Note that there is a build number 217 in the version strings, which is what my build-process sets.

I can also query this information using Powershell. I want to do that in scripts that control deployment:

```
PS D:\> (get-item \\S030A2787\EdiProcessor\Build
\EDIProcessor.Service.exe).VersionInfo | Select-Object *

Comments           : Build 217
CompanyName        : ********
FileBuildPart      : 0
FileDescription    : EDIProcessor.exe
FileMajorPart      : 1
FileMinorPart      : 0
FileName           : \\S030A2787\EdiProcessor\Build\EDIProcessor.Service.exe
FilePrivatePart    : 217
FileVersion        : 1.0.0.217
InternalName       : EDIProcessor
IsDebug            : False
IsPatched          : False
IsPrivateBuild     : False
IsPreRelease       : False
IsSpecialBuild     : False
Language           : Englisch (USA)
LegalCopyright     :
LegalTrademarks    :
OriginalFilename   :
PrivateBuild       :
ProductBuildPart   : 0
ProductMajorPart   : 1
ProductMinorPart   : 0
ProductName        : EDIProcessor
ProductPrivatePart : 217
ProductVersion     : 1.0.0.217
SpecialBuild       :

PS D:\> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      4.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.16406
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

Machine B is a virtual machine running Windows Server 2012 R2. It is where I deploy the executable to, and here I get different unexpected output. Windows Explorer on B says:

[image]

Note that apart from being in a different language, the version strings show up as 1.0.0.0 without the build-number. Powershell agrees:

```
PS Y:\> (get-item \\S030A2787\EDIProcessor\build\EDIProcessor.Service.exe).VersionInfo | Select-Object *

Comments           :
CompanyName        :
FileBuildPart      : 0
FileDescription    : EDIProcessor.Service
FileMajorPart      : 1
FileMinorPart      : 0
FileName           : \\S030A2787\EDIProcessor\build\EDIProcessor.Service.exe
FilePrivatePart    : 0
FileVersion        : 1.0.0.0
InternalName       :
IsDebug            : False
IsPatched          : False
IsPrivateBuild     : False
IsPreRelease       : False
IsSpecialBuild     : False
Language           : English (United States)
LegalCopyright     :
LegalTrademarks    :
OriginalFilename   :
PrivateBuild       :
ProductBuildPart   : 0
ProductMajorPart   : 1
ProductMinorPart   : 0
ProductName        : EDIProcessor.Service
ProductPrivatePart : 0
ProductVersion     : 1.0.0.0
SpecialBuild       :

PS Y:\> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      4.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.18773
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

The executable in question is a Windows Service built in Embarcadero Delphi 10.2 for the Win32 platform. I have added this version info by writing VersionInfo.rc like so:

```
#define VERSION 1,0,0,217
#define VERSION_STR "1.0.0.217\0"
#define COMMENT "Build 217\0"

1 VERSIONINFO
  FILEVERSION VERSION
  PRODUCTVERSION VERSION
  FILEFLAGSMASK 0x0
  FILEFLAGS 0x0
  FILEOS 0x4
  FILETYPE 0x1
  FILESUBTYPE 0x0
BEGIN
  BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
       BLOCK "040904E4"
         BEGIN
            VALUE "Comments",        COMMENT
            VALUE "ProductName",     "EDIProcessor\0"
            VALUE "CompanyName",     "********\0"
            VALUE "InternalName",    "EDIProcessor\0"
            VALUE "FileDescription", "EDIProcessor.exe\0"
            VALUE "FileVersion",     VERSION_STR
            VALUE "ProductVersion",  VERSION_STR
         END
    END
  BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
       VALUE "Translation", 0x0409L, 1252
       VALUE "Translation", 0x0407L, 1252
    END
END
```

And adding that RC file to the project. Obviously the #defines at the top are set accordingly during the checkout from source control. When building I can see the resource compiler is invoked and on the development machine everything is fine.

Can someone tell me why the two machines interpret the same executable's VERSIONINFO in such a radically different way? Am I doing something wrong? And of course most importantly of all: What can I do to fix this?

Thank you for reading this, thank you even more for thinking about my problem.

Comment: The first step to be sure the file really is the same is to [compare its hashes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-filehash?view=powershell-5.1). Both systems should return identical hash. Do they?

Comment: Machine A has language German and machine B has language English. May be you can change machine A to "Englisch (USA)" using `regional settings` in control panel and try again ? Some properties might be language dependent ?

Comment: 0x0409 = 1033 = English (USA)

Comment: Why do you have two "Translation" entries instead of only one that matches the "StringFileInfo" block? Could it be that you actually have multiple version resources in the EXE? I suggest to open the EXE in a proper resource editor to find out.

Comment: I am certain the file is the very same in both attempts, because I am accessing it from the same location, a shared folder.

I have not tried changing the language of my development machine A, because I think that is a bit too drastic and I think version info of an executable should be invariant of that.

I am not sure what the comment about the language code means. On both machines it reports the same for that.

There is no real reason for two translation entries, I was experimenting.

Comment: Solution: Apparently I did have duplicate VERSIONINFO resources in the executable.

I did uncheck the box to include version info under project options in the IDE, but found out now that this setting did not stick. I tried several times, but it always came back checked when I reopened project options.

I then modified the value directly in the dproj-file and that worked. The IDE-setting reflects that by showing an unchecked box and checking version info now gives the same intended values.

Thank you very much!

Remaining open question? Why do the two machines pick up different copies?

Comment: "_Why do the two machines pick up different copies?_" -- The OS tries to pick the version resource that matches the OS locale.

Comment: @MarianAldenhövel please post your comment as an answer. comments are not for this thank you for sharing your solution.